# Call to undefined function field_attach_load() on a newly migrated site

Tags: 7

I am moving a site over to a different server to test.

I am getting the following error:

> Call to undefined function field_attach_load() in my-path-to-root/my-site/includes/entity.inc on line 320

If I try accessing http://www.example.com/randomstuff, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in /home/borsodas3/digipowers.devserver2012.com/modules/overlay/overlay.module on line 130
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_access_needs_rebuild() in /home/borsodas3/digipowers.devserver2012.com/sites/all/modules/taxonomy_access/taxonomy>_access.module on line 598

`phpinfo()` returns following information for the two sites:

- [Source site](http://www.freeenergymedia.com/phpinfo-from.htm)
- [Destination site](http://www.freeenergymedia.com/phpinfo-to.htm)

The Drupal status report from the site I am migrating FROM looks like this:

> Info
> Drupal  7.8
> **OK** Access to update.php Protected
> **Error** CTools CSS Cache  Unable to create
> The CTools CSS cache directory, ctools/css could not be created due to a misconfigured files directory. Please ensure that the files directory is correctly configured and that the webserver has permission to create directories.
> **OK**  Configuration file  Protected
> **OK** Credit card encryption   Credit card data is encrypted during checkout for maximum security.
> **OK** Cron maintenance tasks   Last run 26 min ago
> You can run cron manually.
> To run cron from outside the site, go to mysite.com
> **OK** Database system  MySQL, MariaDB, or equivalent
> **OK** Database system version  5.1.57-log
> **OK** Database updates Up to date
> **OK** Date API System date settings
> The timezone has been set to America/New_York. The first day of the week has been set to Monday. The medium date format has been set to to F j, Y - g:ia.
> **Error** Drupal core update status Not secure! (version 7.12 available)
> There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
> **OK** File system  Writable (public download method)
> **OK** Fitvids library  Installed
> Fitvids Javascript Library. Download it from here, copy it to the module directory, and rename it to jquery.fitvids.js.
> **OK** GD library PNG support   bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
> **OK** GD library rotate and desaturate effects bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
> **OK** Images   Product image support has been automatically configured by Ubercart.
> **Error** Module and theme update status    Not secure!
> There are security updates available for one or more of your modules or themes. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
> **OK** Node Access Permissions  1832 permissions in use
> If the site is experiencing problems with permissions to content, you may have to rebuild the permissions cache. Rebuilding will remove all privileges to content and replace them with permissions based on the current modules and settings. Rebuilding may take some time if there is a lot of content or complex permission settings. After rebuilding has completed, content will automatically use the new permissions. Rebuild permissions
> **OK** PHP  5.3.2 (more information)
> **OK** PHP extensions   Enabled
> **OK** PHP memory limit 300M
> **OK** PHP register globals Disabled
> **Warning** Unicode library Standard PHP
> Operations on Unicode strings are emulated on a best-effort basis. Install the PHP mbstring extension for improved Unicode support.
> **OK** Update notifications Enabled
> **Info**  Upload progress   Not enabled
> Your server is capable of displaying file upload progress through APC, but it is not enabled. Add apc.rfc1867 = 1 to your php.ini configuration. Alternatively, it is recommended to use PECL uploadprogress, which supports more than one simultaneous upload.
> **OK** Web server   Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
> **OK** cURL Enabled

Comment: Those errors generally means Drupal cannot find the files to include and which contain the Drupal core functions. If you don't get any error about the `DRUPAL_ROOT` constant not being defined, or about not existing files passed to `include()`, it could mean Drupal core files are corrupt. Check you have the core files in the directory to which `DRUPAL_ROOT` points.

Comment: so basically you are saying that some files could be currupt or missing?

Comment: That is the more probable reason, but check the index.php file present in the directory where Drupal is installed, and check it is the [standard one](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/7) (click on "View source"); in particular check there is the line with `define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd())`. I don't write this as answer because the question seems too localized. If a canonical question can be written, I could think adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem today and I fixed it by simply running the update script:

The update script is located in the root folder of your Drupal 7 install.
eg.

> www.mynewlymigratedtoserver.com/update.php

One other thing you should probably know, you have to be logged in to run the update script, you can login right? No, you can't! That's ok, there's a work around.

In your settings.php (usually /sites/default/settings.php) there is a line (231 for me) that says this:

> $update_free_access = FALSE;

This variable determines if the update script can be used by anyone, not just logged in people. Set it to **TRUE** and you'll be able to run the update script. You'll want to set it back to false when you're done.

If that didn't work try [this](http://drupaldose.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/drupal-fatal-error-call-to-undefined.html)